# is a sata DVD burner really worth the extra cash 

Tags: windows-7, sata, dvd-burning, pata

My computer has a old school PATA (ide) DVD burner that works fast and great, really it is the only thing I've not updated over the years. is there any advantage to upgrading to a Sata DVD drive.

Comment: Most new motherboards no longer include IDE controllers.  But until you make that leap, your old IDE burner will do fine.

Comment: Clarified the question and removed text that made it look like a shopping question, consider voting to re-open this question.

Comment: IDK about this one... look at the answer it has already generated. It basically states if you like the way it looks and feels keep it... I can't see this question attracting any quality answers, I can't in good faith vote to reopen this.

Comment: @J.Taylor: Please read the FAQ, this is not a forum but a site for questions based on actual practical problems. The technical specifications of PATA and SATA are listed online, comparison of both standards is not so hard...

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with your old one, the way it looks, and if fits into your new computer connector-wise, then the answer if that it is fine, and you could spend the money better elsewhere.